# Implicit function theorem for manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Suppose $x_1,..,x_k$ form a local coordinate on a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X\subset \bf{R^n}.$ Show that, there exists smooth function $g$ defined on an   open set $U$ in $\bf{R^k}$ such that $V$ may be taken to be $\{(x,g(x))\in \bf{R^n}:x\in U\}.$

This is basically implicit function theorem. But, since I am an beginner , I want someone to check my solution.

Consider, the function, $h:V\to\mathbb{R}^k$ defined by, $h=(x_1,...,x_k)$ which is smooth.
Since, $x_1,..,x_k$ form a local coordinate on $V$ so $h$ is a submersion  therefore by submersion theorem for each $x\in V$ there exists open sets $U(\subset\mathbb{R}^k)$ and smooth function $g_1:U\to X$  ( where $g_1(u)=(g_2(u),g_3(u))\in\mathbb{R^k}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$) such that $h(g_1(u))=u $,so $g_2(u)=u$  hence if we take $g(u)=\pi_2\circ g_1 (u)=g_3(u)$ then  the problem is solved.

Comment: $\phi \times \psi$ has image not in $X$, but an open set in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @Arctic Char will you take a look at it now?

Comment: It's not clear how submersion theorem is used. $h : V\to \mathbb R^k$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, this is more or less the definition of a coordinates. So it has a smooth inverse $g_1$. What is that $\pi_2$?

Comment: I agree I should be more explicit. $g_1$ is local coordinate map,due to submersion theorem we can say that $h$ looks like Identity map and $\pi_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is the projection map. Thank you for your patience. Please check it and I can clarify more if you want. @Arctic Char

Comment: Is there any way you can make your last sentence in the proof "hence if we take $\pi_2 \circ g_1(u)=g(u)$ the problem is solved." precise?

Comment: Can you check now, @Arctic Char